# nginx proxy_pass dynamic hostname part

Tags: nginx

When nginx proxy_pass is a dynamic value expected to be build by substituting hostname part in URL, nginx is failing to proxy request with error: *no resolver defined to resolve **service** where **service**=$1*. Instead of trying to resolve service.abcd.local, it seems it is trying to resolve just **service**. Is there solution to this ?

```
location ~ ^/(.*)/(.*)$ {
  proxy_pass http://$1.abcd.local/$1/$2;   
}
```

Comment: have you added a resolver (`resolver` directive)?

Comment: BTW, for url like `/a/b/c/d` your regexp will result in `$1 = /a/b/c`, `$2 = d`, and proxy url will be `http://a/b/c/.abcd.local/....`, and nginx absolutely right to try to resolve hostname `a`.

Comment: Alexey - Thanks. That is correct. regex was wrong. After fixing regex, still it is failing attempting to resolve service.abcd.local. If proxy_pass is hardcoded as http://service.abcd.local nginx is resolving and is able to proxy.

Comment: And again, have you added `resolver`?

Comment: No - is explicit resolver required ? nginx is running in amazon VPC with *.abcd.local resolving.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As specified in nginx's doc [`proxy_pass`](http://nginx.org/r/proxy_pass):

> A server name, its port and the passed URI can also be specified using variables:
>
> ```
> proxy_pass http://$host$uri;
> ```
>
> […]
>
> In this case, the server name is searched among the described **server groups**, and, if not found, is determined using a **resolver**.

Comment: So this means if a variable is present in proxy_pass, a resolver has to be explicitly specified ?

Comment: Yes, if variable present in host part. Or, you have to define **server group** for all possible hosts.

Comment: That clarifies things. Thanks.